# How to listen to changes in psuedo-classes on JavaFX nodes

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I had assumed that I could listen to changes on `Node.getPseudoClassStates()` as it is of type `ObservableSet`, however no change events or invalidations are fired.

Is there any other way to listen to changes in which psuedo-classes are set on a Node.

```
public class PsuedoEvents extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Button horse = new Button("horse");
        horse.getPseudoClassStates().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            @Override
            public void invalidated(Observable arg0) {
                System.out.println("invalidated " + arg0);
            }
        });
        horse.getPseudoClassStates().addListener(new SetChangeListener<>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends PseudoClass> arg0) {
                System.out.println("changed " + arg0);
            }
        });
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new HBox(horse), 300, 300));
        PseudoClass fooClass = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("foo");

        horse.setOnAction(event -> {
            horse.pseudoClassStateChanged(fooClass, !horse.getPseudoClassStates().contains(fooClass));
            System.out.println("Toggle state... " + horse.getPseudoClassStates());
        });
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: That's working for me... Tried JDK 1.8.0_161 and JDK 9.0.1

Comment: Thanks for checking, I'm using 9.0.4

Comment: @James_D This is really spooky, nothing seems to have changed in JavaFX, the collection wrappers have always used weak references but behaves differently in 9.0.4....

Comment: Maybe GC implementation changed... GC was going to be my next guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to identify the issue... `getPseudoClassStates()` returns a unmodifiable wrapper.

```
public final ObservableSet<PseudoClass> getPseudoClassStates() {
    return FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableSet(pseudoClassStates);
}
```

The wrapper type `UnmodifiableObservableSet` uses a weak listener to track the backing list, however since there is no strong reference to the wrapper it is garbage collected.

I can workaround this using

```
private ObservableSet<PseudoClass> states;  // <=== strong ref

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Button horse = new Button("horse");

    states = horse.getPseudoClassStates();
    states.addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
        @Override
        public void invalidated(Observable arg0) {
            System.out.println("invalidated " + arg0);
        }
    });
```